# React JS function within Sort returning Null

Tags: javascript, reactjs, function, sorting, null

It feels like JS is having me on with something that would normally work, but the subtle tricks with JS and React are tripping it up this time.

So, the **current** code:

```
 GetSortedMarkets() {
   events = events.sort(function (a, b) {
      const aMarket = a.Markets.find(m => { 
            const mType = m.markettype;
            const mName = m.name;

            if (mType !== null && mType.toUpperCase().includes("MONEY")) return true;
            else if (mName == "Money" || (mName == "MONEY")) return true;
            else return false;
      });

      const bMarket = b.Markets.find(m => { 
            const mType = m.markettype;
            const mName = m.name;
            
            if (mType !== null && mType.toUpperCase().includes("MONEY")) return true;
            else if (mName == "Money" || (mName == "MONEY")) return true; 
            else return false; 
      });

      return aMarket.marketPosition - bMarket.marketPosition;
   });
}
```

*This works just fine. However, the find function used to get a/b market is used twice here and once elsewhere. To reduce code duplication, I moved the functionality out into a separate method.*

The **new** code:

```
GetMoneyMarket(markets) {
   return markets.find(m => {
      const mType = m.markettype;
      const mName = m.name;
        
      if (mType !== null && mType.toUpperCase().includes("MONEY")) return true;
      else if (mName == "Money" || (mName == "MONEY")) return true; 
      else return false;
   });
}

GetSortedMarkets() { 
   events = events.sort(function (a, b) {
      const aMarket = this.GetMoneyMarket(a.Markets);
      const bMarket = this.GetMoneyMarket(b.Markets);
      return aMarket.marketPosition - bMarket.marketPosition;
   });
}
```

The problem I am now having is it seems to be trying to continue after the function GetMoneyMarket before it has finished executing and returning a value. So the return throws an exception as it tries to load a property of an object that has not yet been loaded.

From research so far, one suggestion seems to be React executing in its own console in a different order than what would be expected looking at the code. I would expect it to execute line by line synchronously.

The methods could also now be trying to execute asynchronously, to which I tried to force them to wait for completion to no success. Though it is possible I did this incorrectly.

The unideal solution is to leave the code duplicated. It is not many lines of code and it works when no outside function is involved. However, it seems like something that *should* work, and it is better to solve this now so I am prepared for something that you can't just leave duplicated later.

Thank for reading.

**Update -** Error Message: *TypeError: Cannot read property 'GetMoneyMarket' of undefined*

Comment: Could you post the exact error that you get? In the example, the `this` keyword might not be referring to what you expect it to. It'll be a bit easier to figure that out if you can create a jsfiddle example or add the containing block the thee example. The execution order should be synchronous here.

Comment: @nipuna777 "TypeError: Cannot read property 'GetMoneyMarket' of undefined.
"
That was another thing I suspected and forgot to mention. If going inside the sort changes what "this" is in reference too.

Comment: Could you the sort function an arrow function and see if that helps? `(a, b) => {`
`

Comment: In what context is this `GetSortedMarkets` called? Is it from an event handler?

Comment: @nipuna777 Seems I will be researching the subtle differences between arrow and specified functions! That seemed to do the trick.

DaveNewton All of the methods being called are just within the React class being called with this.MethodName. 
It would seem the differences I am about to research between function(a,b)/ (a,b) => are to blame for my issues. 

Thank you both for the contributions.

Answer (score 0):

Thanks to the suggestions from https://stackoverflow.com/users/3156644/nipuna777, the solution seems to have been found.

The problem seemed to be because of a difference of regular functions and arrow functions. Changing my sort function to contain an arrow rather than a regular seemed to allow the methods within to find and run the logic they were supposed to.

I will now be referring to https://dmitripavlutin.com/differences-between-arrow-and-regular-functions/ to see what I can learn about the differences that causes this issue. The link is here for anyone else who wants to do the same after having this issue.